# Составить запрос: получить дату из строки и сравнить её с параметром типа дата

Tags: 1с, запрос

Ясного неба!

**1с предприятие 8.2 (8.2.15.289)**

В табличной части документа есть поле с составным типом данных. Одним из типов является строка. Строка всегда имеет подобный вид "10.10.2012 - 10.10.2013", и даты могут быть различными.

Мне нужно в запросе каким-то образом выцепить вторую дату из строки (в данном случае "10.10.2013") и сравнить ее с параметром типа дата.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Начну издалека - сегодня я начал ненавидеть 1С еще сильнее.*

А теперь по делу.

Два дня серфил, чтобы найти ответ на вопрос. В итоге получилась такая незамысловатая конструкция запроса:

```
ДОБАВИТЬКДАТЕ(ДОБАВИТЬКДАТЕ(ДОБАВИТЬКДАТЕ(&НачалоМ, Год,
                            ВЫБОР
                                Когда подстрока(выразить(ТабличнаяЧасть.НомерВыхода как строка(23)), 22, 2) = "13"
                                ТОГДА 2012
                                КОНЕЦ), месяц,

                ВЫБОР
                    Когда подстрока(выразить(ТабличнаяЧасть.НомерВыхода как строка(23)), 17, 2) = "05"
                    ТОГДА 4
                    КОНЕЦ), день,  
ВЫБОР
    Когда подстрока(выразить(ТабличнаяЧасть.НомерВыхода как строка(23)), 14, 2) = "29"
    ТОГДА 28
    ИНАЧЕ
ВЫБОР
    Когда подстрока(выразить(ТабличнаяЧасть.НомерВыхода как строка(23)), 14, 2) = "30"
    ТОГДА 29
    ИНАЧЕ
ВЫБОР
    Когда подстрока(выразить(ТабличнаяЧасть.НомерВыхода как строка(23)), 14, 2) = "31"
    ТОГДА 30
КОНЕЦ
КОНЕЦ
КОНЕЦ
```

Прошу заметить, что данный запрос учитывает только один год, только один месяц, и три последних дня. Значит надо добавить сюда over9000 строк кода, чтобы просматривались еще хотя бы несколько лет (с запасом), все 12 месяцев и 31 день...

---

А все потому что функция **ДАТАВРЕМЯ** не понимает в аргументах другие функции, а если бы и понимала, то в запросе нельзя представить строку датой, кроме как вышепредставленным **онанизмом**.

---

*нельзя просто так взять и написать нормальный запрос*

Comment: Ну это не дело, конечно. Надо идти верным путем. Добавить два реквизита, обработкой туда данные перекинуть, конвертнув их в дату. В общем структура данных порочная.

Comment: Структура местами ужасная. Я порой просто плачу. Я бы руки отрубил тому, кто это все делал.

Comment: А почему не получиться выделить подстроку:  

    10.10.2013
переделать ее в строку:  

    20131010
а потом уже:  

    ДАТА("20131010")
сравнивать с чем угодно типа «дата»  
?

Comment: потому что в запросах 1С нельзя приводить типы данных, а два разных типа сравнивать нельзя. Поэтому приходится собирать дату по кусочкам

Answer (score 0):

Смотри функции `ПОДСТРОКА` и `ДАТАВРЕМЯ`

Comment: Неверные параметры "ДАТАВРЕМЯ"
(ДатаВремя(<<?>>Подстрока(выразить(ТабличнаяЧасть.НомерВыхода как строка(23)), 20, 23),

Comment: сначала подстрока 12 символов с конца, а потом датавремя.

Comment: @uilenspiegel,  
1. функция ДАТАВРЕМЯ принимает аргументы в таком формате: ДАТАВРЕМЯ(гггг, мм, дд, чч, мм, сс), поэтому нельзя просто так взять и запихнуть туда имеющуюся строку.  
2. почему 12-то символов? в дате их 10. Мне не нужны тире и пробел перед датой.  
3. ДАТАВРЕМЯ ругается у меня на подстроки в любом их виде.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать наоборот. Привести параметр типа "дата" к "строке" или сразу передавать этот параметр как строку, из табличной части вырезать вторую дату и сравнивать

Answer (score -2):

Хоть и много времени прошло, но может пригодится кому-нибудь, кто случайно заглянет в эту тему (сам когда-то мучался над подобной проблемой):

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    0 КАК Цифра,
    "0" КАК Буква
ПОМЕСТИТЬ ЦифраБуква

ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ

ВЫБРАТЬ
    1,
    "1"

ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ

ВЫБРАТЬ
    2,
    "2"

ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ

ВЫБРАТЬ
    3,
    "3"

ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ

ВЫБРАТЬ
    4,
    "4"

ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ

ВЫБРАТЬ
    5,
    "5"

ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ

ВЫБРАТЬ
    6,
    "6"

ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ

ВЫБРАТЬ
    7,
    "7"

ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ

ВЫБРАТЬ
    8,
    "8"

ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ

ВЫБРАТЬ
    9,
    "9"
;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ЦифраБуква.Цифра
ПОМЕСТИТЬ День1
ИЗ
    ЦифраБуква КАК ЦифраБуква
ГДЕ
    ЦифраБуква.Буква = ПОДСТРОКА(&СтрокаДат, &НачальныйСимвол, 1)
;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ЦифраБуква.Цифра
ПОМЕСТИТЬ День2
ИЗ
    ЦифраБуква КАК ЦифраБуква
ГДЕ
    ЦифраБуква.Буква = ПОДСТРОКА(&СтрокаДат, &НачальныйСимвол + 1, 1)
;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ЦифраБуква.Цифра
ПОМЕСТИТЬ Месяц1
ИЗ
    ЦифраБуква КАК ЦифраБуква
ГДЕ
    ЦифраБуква.Буква = ПОДСТРОКА(&СтрокаДат, &НачальныйСимвол + 3, 1)
;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ЦифраБуква.Цифра
ПОМЕСТИТЬ Месяц2
ИЗ
    ЦифраБуква КАК ЦифраБуква
ГДЕ
    ЦифраБуква.Буква = ПОДСТРОКА(&СтрокаДат, &НачальныйСимвол + 4, 1)
;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ЦифраБуква.Цифра
ПОМЕСТИТЬ Год1
ИЗ
    ЦифраБуква КАК ЦифраБуква
ГДЕ
    ЦифраБуква.Буква = ПОДСТРОКА(&СтрокаДат, &НачальныйСимвол + 6, 1)
;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ЦифраБуква.Цифра
ПОМЕСТИТЬ Год2
ИЗ
    ЦифраБуква КАК ЦифраБуква
ГДЕ
    ЦифраБуква.Буква = ПОДСТРОКА(&СтрокаДат, &НачальныйСимвол + 7, 1)
;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ЦифраБуква.Цифра
ПОМЕСТИТЬ Год3
ИЗ
    ЦифраБуква КАК ЦифраБуква
ГДЕ
    ЦифраБуква.Буква = ПОДСТРОКА(&СтрокаДат, &НачальныйСимвол + 8, 1)
;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ЦифраБуква.Цифра
ПОМЕСТИТЬ Год4
ИЗ
    ЦифраБуква КАК ЦифраБуква
ГДЕ
    ЦифраБуква.Буква = ПОДСТРОКА(&СтрокаДат, &НачальныйСимвол + 9, 1)
;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ДОБАВИТЬКДАТЕ(ДОБАВИТЬКДАТЕ(ДОБАВИТЬКДАТЕ(ДАТАВРЕМЯ(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), ДЕНЬ, 10 * День1.Цифра + День2.Цифра - 1), МЕСЯЦ, 10 * Месяц1.Цифра + Месяц2.Цифра - 1), ГОД, 1000 * Год1.Цифра + 100 * Год2.Цифра + 10 * Год3.Цифра + Год4.Цифра - 1) КАК КонечнаяДата
ИЗ
    День1 КАК День1
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ День2 КАК День2
        ПО (ИСТИНА)
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Месяц1 КАК Месяц1
        ПО (ИСТИНА)
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Месяц2 КАК Месяц2
        ПО (ИСТИНА)
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Год1 КАК Год1
        ПО (ИСТИНА)
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Год2 КАК Год2
        ПО (ИСТИНА)
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Год3 КАК Год3
        ПО (ИСТИНА)
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Год4 КАК Год4
        ПО (ИСТИНА)
```

Параметры:

- `СтрокаДат` - как в первом сообщении,
- `НачальныйСимвол` = 14 в данном случае.

Comment: Какой-то ад. Ещё и плохо отформатирован.